# Yii2: How to redirect to with UrlManager?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In my Yii2 config I have:

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [

        'baseUrl'         => '',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName'  => false,

        'rules' => [
            'search' => 'site/index',
            ...
        ],
    ...
```

If I go to `site.com/search` it works. If I go to `site.com/site/index` it also works and shows the same content. How to redirect the call instead of just showing the response of site/index? It must also redirect with params (`site.com/site/index?param=1` -> `site.com/search?param=1`)

Comment: not sure what you are asking

Comment: /search and /site/index works and this is the expected behavior. But if you need help only about params, let me know and I can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UrlManager does not redirect. It rather does a [rewrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) like a web server. It is called [routing](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing).

If you would like to do a redirect in your code you can use [`Response::redirect()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#redirect()-detail). If you don't have a `SearchController` where you can put this statement in an action, you can place it into the [`beforeAction`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-applications#beforeAction) event. You can do this in your configuration array:

#### Option #1

```
[
    'components' = [
        ...
    ],
    'on beforeAction' => function ($event) {
        if(Yii::$app->request->pathInfo === 'search') {
            $url = 'site/index?' . Yii::$app->request->queryString;
            Yii::$app->response->redirect($url)->send();
            $event->handled = true;
        }
    }
]
```

#### Option #2

Or if you have `SearchController` use:

```
class SearchController extends \yii\web\Controller {
    public function actionIndex() {
        $url = 'site/index?' . Yii::$app->request->queryString;
        return $this->redirect($url);
    }
}
```

#### Option #3

Third option is to configure the web server to do the redirect. **That would be the fastest solution**.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `redirect` that's much easier and it solves your problem, it's just like the `render`. See the example below:

```
 return $this->redirect(['/site/index']);
```

P.S. The path can be an absolute or relative, you could also use an alias or anything else, here is an example:

```
// an alias of for home page
Yii::setAlias('@home', 'site/index');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`UrlManager::$enableStrictParsing`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlmanager#$enableStrictParsing-detail) to disable matching by route. If you set it to `true`, request to `/site/index` URL will not match anything and app will return 404 error.

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'baseUrl' => '',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'rules' => [
            'search' => 'site/index',
            // ...
        ],
    // ...
```

But this may be not an option if you actually want to use routes as URLs in other cases.

---

You may also be interested in the [`UrlNormalizer`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlnormalizer) class. This is still a relatively simple component and does not (yet) support your use case, but in fact it was designed for such tasks. You may consider extending it and add redirection logic for your use case - it should be much more clean solution than using events or dedicated actions and rules for redirections. It may be also a good material for PR and pushing this feature to core framework.

---

Lazy solution would be to create redirection action and add rules to match URLs that needs to be redirect:

```
class RedirectController extends Controller {

    public function actionRedirect($action, $controller, $module = null) {
        if ($action === $this->action->id && $controller === $this->id && $module === null) {
            // prevent to access action directly and redirection loops
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        $url = Yii::$app->request->get();
        unset($url['action'], $url['controller'], $url['module']);
        array_unshift($url, '/' . ltrim(implode('/', [$module, $controller, $action]), '/'));

        return $this->redirect($url);
    }
}
```

And rules:

```
'urlManager' => [
    // ...
    'rules' => [
        'search' => 'site/index',
        [
            'pattern' => '<controller:(site)>/<action:(index)>',
            'route' => 'redirect/redirect',
            'model' => UrlRule::PARSING_ONLY,
        ],
        // ...
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will more pricise and lil bit universally. In config:

```
'components' => [
],
'on beforeAction' => function ($event) {
    list($route, $params) = Yii::$app->urlManager->parseRequest(Yii::$app->request);
    $params = $_GET;

    if (is_string(Yii::$app->request->pathInfo)
        && strpos(Yii::$app->request->pathInfo, $route) === 0
    ) {
        if (strpos($route, '/') === false) {
            $route .= '/index';
        }

        $url = array_merge([0 => $route], $params);

        foreach(Yii::$app->urlManager->rules as $rule) {
            if ($rule->route === $route) {
                Yii::$app->response->redirect($url)->send();
                $event->handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
},
```